# How do I use grep to scan a folder of .scss files and remove the first line if it is blank?

Tags: bash, grep, workflow

I am getting into linux and optimizing my workflow and would love an example. I have a whole bunch of .scss inside of nested folders and I need to check if the first line is blank, and if so delete it, then re-save the file. I'm working on windows at work, but like writing bash. I've experimented with :

```
grep -r "/^\n/"
```

But seems to return every blank line. Then I'm not too sure how to delete it and then re-save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may get you started:

```
find . -name '*.scss' -exec sed -i.bak '1{/^$/d}' {} \;
```

To understand this command, we can break it into two parts:

1. `find . -name '*.scss' -exec ... \;`

   Starting with the current directory, this looks recursively for files with names ending with `.scss` and, when it finds one, it runs the command that follows `-exec` on it.
2. `sed -i.bak '1{/^$/d}' {}`

   `sed` is a stream editor.  The option `-i.bak` tells it to change files in-place, leaving behind back backup file.  Before `find` runs this command, it will replace `{}` with the actual name of the file that it found.

   `1{...}'` tells sed to select the first line of the file and apply to it the commands in braces.

   `/^$/` is a regular expression.  It matches a line if the line is empty.

   `d` tells sed to delete any matching line.

   So, let's put that all together: if the first line of the file is empty, sed deletes it.

You will find many tutorials on the web on both `find` and `sed`.  You can find detailed information on either using `man find` or `man sed`.

Comment: Thanks that's a really good explanation. I will check out the tutorials too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use`grep` to edit files, you should use `sed`.

https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html